# total of dynamic input

Tags: javascript

hello I have 3 type of input.  I have dynamic create by a add button

```
  //function append mardi
var countermardi = 0;
 var $newRow ; 
$(function(){
    $('#add_mardi').click(function(){
        countermardi += 1;

        $newRow = $('<input id="nummar' + countermardi + '" name="nummar[]' + '" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" /> ')     ;   $('#nummar').append($newRow)

        $newRow.keypress (function (e) { return handledynmar(event, this, 'task');}) 

                    $newRow.autocomplete(autocompOpt);
               $('#clientmar').append(
                    (    '<input id="clientmar' + countermardi + '" name="clientmar[]' + '" type="text"  onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" />')  

                )
                $('#prodescmar').append(
                    (    '<input id="prodescmar' + countermardi + '" name="prodescmar[]' + '" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" />')     
                    )
                $('#protachemar').append(
                    (    '<textarea id="protachemar' + countermardi + '" name="protachemar[]' + '" type="text"  rows="1" cols="20" />')     
                    )
                $('#prolieudivmar').append(
                    (    '<input id="prolieudivmar' + countermardi + '" name="prolieudivmar[]' + '" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" />')   
                    )
                select = $('<select id="tachedivmar' + countermardi + '" name="tachedivmar[]" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" />');
                select.append($("#Selectmardi option").clone());
                $("#tachedivmar").append(select);

                $('#calculTempsdivmar').append(
                    (    '<input id="calculTempsdivmar' + countermardi + '" name="calculTempsdivmar[]' + '" type="number" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0" class="dynamic" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" />')    
                    )   
    });
});
```

I have the total of the days calculate by X input for 1 days.

```
<td>
        <span id="calculTemps2">
            <div id="calculTempsdivmar">
                <input step="any"  id="temps3" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" type="number" class= "temps"  name="tempsma" size="2" min="0" max="24" value="0"/></br>
            </div>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="tempsmartotal"> 
                <input step="any" type="text" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" id="tempsmartotal"  class="temps"  name="tempsmartotal" size="5"  value="0"/><br/>
            </div >
    </td>

</tr>
```

and I have the total all days.

```
<input type="text" id="result" readonly="readonly" name="total" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();" />
```

Here how I make a calcul in a static ways

```
//mercredi
$("#calculTemps3").on('change','input.temps',function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".temps").each(function() {
        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#result").val(total);
});
```

So how I calculate my new calculTempsdivmar for thurdays?

Answer (score 0):

use length

```
$("#calculTemps3").on('blur','input.temps',function() {
    var total = $(this).find('input').length;

    $("#result").val(total);
});
```

Comment: doest work. I need to calculate calculTempsdivmar dynamicly and add the result into calculTemps3